# How to use Laravel Requests in Livewire Components

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

How to use exactly the same rules that I use in Laravel Requests in Livewire Components? I have already build Request in Laravel and I don't want to rebuild it in Livewire. In Livewire i can't use Laravel option (e.g. \App\Rules). What is the best way to solve this problem because we also have api calls through controllers?

Comment: What do you mean you can't use `App\Rules`? Some code with your question would make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean [Laravel Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation). By default [this feature is not possible](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/990) to use in Livewire.

But what you can do is the following if you have an `update` method in your Livewire component.

```php
public function update(ProfileUpdateRequest $request)
{
    $this->validate($request->rules());

    // ...
}
```

With that you can bundle the validation in the form request class.

You can also use your single rules inside a `rules()` method Livewire components

```
use App\Rules\CustomRule;

//.. other stuff

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => ['required', new CustomRule()],
        'content' => 'required|min:10'
    ];
}
```

See [Livewire Validation](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation) for details.

Comment: I updated my comment to reflect the `rules()` method instead of the `rules` property. This gives you possiblity to use your already existing rules.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function submit()
{
    $this->validate((new StoreOrderRequest())->rules());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `rules()` as a method instead of a property

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;


public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => ['required', new MyRule()],
        'content' => 'required|min:10'
    ];
}
```